# Finding a one line solution to pass variable arguments to an R script

Tags: bash

I have two principal data files (datafile1 and datafile2) that are split by chromosome, so I have a number of files that look like this:

```
datafile1_chr1.txt
datafile1_chr2.txt
datafile1_chr3.txt

datafile2_chr1.txt
datafile2_chr2.txt
datafile2_chr3.txt
```

I'm trying to write a bit of Bash code that can identify the two datafiles from the same chromosome and run an R script using those two files as variables.

What I have at the moment is very verbose:

```
Rscript --vanilla matchdata.R datafile1_chr1.txt datafile2_chr1.txt
Rscript --vanilla matchdata.R datafile1_chr2.txt datafile2_chr2.txt
Rscript --vanilla matchdata.R datafile1_chr3.txt datafile2_chr3.txt
```

Could someone suggest a one line solution for this?  I am not sure how I could encorporate variables to help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop should be enough:

```
for i in {1..3}
do
    Rscript --vanilla matchdata.R datafile1_chr${i}.txt datafile2_chr${i}.txt
done
```

Or, in one line:

```
for i in {1..3}; do Rscript --vanilla matchdata.R datafile{1,2}_chr${i}.txt; done
```

Note the second use of brace expansion (`{1,2}`) - that should expand `datafile{1,2}_chr${i}.txt` into `datafile1_chr${i}.txt datafile2_chr${i}.txt`.